# How to Improve Accuracy of Iteration?

Tags: c++, performance, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to make code, c++, to plot the Mandlebrot Set. However, whenever I run my code, see below, the convergence is poor. How do I fix that? I provided some code below. There's also a screenshot of the Mandelbrot Set, red, and my code's approximation, greyscale.

```
  #include <GL/glut.h>

void renderscene(void) {

  double x=0;
  double y=0;
  double ix=0;
  double iy=0;
  int n=1;

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  for(x=-3;x<3;x=x+0.01){
    for(y=-3;y<3;y=y+0.01){

      for(n=1;n<50;n=n+1){
        ix=ix*ix-iy*iy+x;
        iy=2*iy*ix+y;
        if(ix*ix+iy*iy>4){
          break;
        }
      }

      ix=0;
      iy=0;

      glPointSize(1);
      glColor3f(0.1*n,0.1*n,0.1*n);
      glBegin(GL_POINTS);
      glVertex2f(x*0.4,y*0.4);
      glEnd();
    }
  }

  glutSwapBuffers();

}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowPosition(300,200);
  glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
  glutCreateWindow("Hello");

  glutDisplayFunc(renderscene);

  glutMainLoop();

  return 1;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want accuracy, don't use floating point operations.

Comment: @Rhymoid I was wondering the same. It works because they are init'ed to 0 and reset to zero after each pixel. But of course, one would usually just init the to zeor in the inner loop (depending on the compiler, this might even allow for better optimization)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah, I noticed the `ix = 0; iy = 0;` later. It's not the most readable code. I doubt compilers would perform better than when `ix` and `iy` are declared within the `for(y-=3; ...)`-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong `ix` in the computation of the new `iy`.

Try

```
double nextix=ix*ix-iy*iy+x;
iy=2*iy*ix+y;
ix = nextix;
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks for the help!